# adb logcat binary mode ignores filterspecs?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

In `adb shell`

```
$ logcat -B -s MyTag
$ logcat -B MyTag:I *:S
```

Above two commands receive logs only tag `MyTag` in binary stream.
But it seems to ignore [filterspecs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#filteringOutput) argument only in *binary* mode.

I cannot find any clue to be ignored at [logcat.cpp code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/master/logcat/logcat.cpp)

Is it possible to apply filterspec with `-B` binary format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logcat` code is pretty clear:

```
if (context->printBinary) {
    printBinary(context, &log_msg);
} else {
    processBuffer(context, dev, &log_msg);
}
```

If `context->printBinary` is set to `1` by specifying the `-B` parameter - the `printBinary()` is invoked, which does not do any additional processing (like filtering).